# Imported frameworks but Unity iOS project still won't build with Google AdMobs

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I added the Google Mobile Ads plugin to a Unity project as instructed in Google's videos and when I go to build in Xcode I get a bunch of Link errors. I tried adding frameworks to my project as mentioned in some other posts.  Here's a screenshot of all the frameworks I currently have in the project. [image]

I also made sure that C and Objective-C modules were turned to Yes in Xcode. 
 When I build I'm still get 58 Apple Mach-O Linker Errors, some of which are shown below. [image]

Does anyone know why I might be getting these errors?  It's become a multi-day project just to get banner ads set up in my project and I would appreciate the help.  The project was build through Unity, which contains the Google plugin.  I ran the I'm using the .xcworkspace as instructed.

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1: 
You should add MobileCoreServices.framework and GLKit.framework 
Now Try to Build, if failed follow next step

Step - 2: 
Disable C and Objective-C modules 
Now Try to Build, if failed follow next step

Step - 3: 
Add GoogleMobileAds.framework in unity/Assets/Plugin/iOS/ 
Follow Step - 1 
Now Try to Build